# A modelbox for jQuery 1.3.2

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery 1.3.2 and I was wondering if anyone knew of a modelbox/lightbox that would work with that.  I've found a bunch of jQuery powered lightboxes, but most of them use way older versions of jQuery.

I am going to use it to display an html form so it need it to support more than just images.

Thanks

--

I ended up going with colorbox because it's really pretty good.  The only downside I can see is that if doesn't recenter after you re-size the browser window, but I can live without that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ColorBox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) is one that I found recently and seems similar in capability to Thickbox.  Their main page indicates it was built against jQuery 1.3.

The particular features that were important to me were:

- Appearance is completely controlled through CSS so users can restyle the box.
- Degrades gracefully, all content displayed can be accessed without JavaScript.
- Generates W3C valid XHTML and CSS, JSLint free with no added global variables.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's anything specifically for 1.3.2 as it is pretty recent.

Even though [Thickbox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/) is ancient, it still works well and lets you show anything you want in the modal.

Also check out [jqModal](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/) for a little newer plugin with some features Thickbox lacks like callbacks.

I've used both of these with >1.3 jQuery versions with no problems and they are very good.

Answer (score 0):

We've used both [SimpleModal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) and [FancyBox](http://fancy.klade.lv/) and had good results.

Answer (score 0):

**Slimbox 2:** http://www.digitalia.be/software/slimbox2

Works perfectly for me with jQuery 1.3.2, and is as simple as original LightBox.

Comment: The OP needs to display an HTML form, not images.